# Template Matching in Playing Cards

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I'm attempting to take images of playing cards and extract information about them using some form of template matching. To start off I've been using Gaussian blurring, gray scale conversion and then thresholding to create a binarised image, and they've been pretty effective at isolating the card as the only real details in the images:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjtym.jpg

However before proceeding to the next step (hopefully using OpenCV's template matching stuff) I was struggling with two things: firstly, do these images need more processing before template matching? For instance, do I need to be looking into accounting for the scale and orientation of the cards? Quick note: the template I was intending to use was the corner of the card with the rank and suit (it's in the link above). I conceptually understand that you can potentially select the entire area by finding the four corner with the internal angles, but I'm pretty clueless on how to implement that. Secondly: is there a particular template matching algorithm that would be best for this type of work? I'd rather do some more processing prior to template matching rather than brute force matching with multiple types of the same image (rotated and scaled to account for the differences in each photo).

So summary: do I need to do some more processing for scale and orientation before matching (and if so, suggested algorithms?), and what template matching algorithm would be the best approach for this problem?

I think the ideal solution is finding the entire card and forming a separate image where it is scaled and positioned for template matching and then using a matching algorithm, but I'm not sure that's even possible! Any help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working with a specific set of cards, then all you need to do (assuming the cards do not overlap), is to find the contours (http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html) of the cards, map the inverse perspective transform to get a straight card image, and then use your template matching.

If, however, you want to be more robust to deck changes, you may also need to detect the inner contours of the numbers / letters / suit shapes, and recognize those to classify the card.

Comment: It will be a specific set of cards. Should I be able to find the contours from a thresholded image, or will it need Canny applied? Also do you know of any OpenCV method to map the inverse perspective transform? I was looking for a resource describing how to implement that process, but I was struggling to understand. I know that the inverse perspective transform would place the card straight on, but the finer details are troubling me.

Comment: Just another comment, I was reading that it was possible to create a reverse perspective from the corner co-ordinates of the card. Using Canny or the binary images I created, is it possible to detect the cards and find their corners, and from their reverse the perspective to produce a straight look at the card?

Comment: You can use edge detection (e.g. canny) on the thresholded image to get an image that you can use a hough transform on.  Then, you can detect the corners by finding line intersections.  Although a full 3D solution that uses the camera's calibration matrices would be preferrable, you can just take the card's image, un-shear it to make it straight and go from there.   Should give a reasonably good result.

Comment: Okay, I was trying to use that corner detection earlier but I couldn't seems to detect lines with Hough. These are the images I've generated from Canny on the threshold image: http://imgur.com/a/l4Kjd Are these suitable for the rest of the processing? I'll looking into what un-shearing is and then hopefully I can detect these corners. Thank you very much for your help and apologies for bothering you.